# With Slick2D, how to change the resolution during gameplay?

Tags: java, window, resolution, slick2d

I am developing a tile-based strategy game using Java and the Slick2D API.

So far so good, but I've come to a standstill on my options menu. I have plans for the user to be able to change the resolution during gameplay (it is pretty common, after all).

I can already change to fullscreen and back to windowed, this was pretty simple...

```
//"fullScreenOption" is a checkbox-like button.
if (fullScreenOption.isMouseOver(mouseX, mouseY)) {
   if (input.isMouseButtonDown(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)) {
      fullScreenOption.state = !fullScreenOption.state;
      container.setFullscreen(fullScreenOption.state);
   }
}
```

But the container class (Implemented by Slick, not me), contrary to my previous beliefs, does not seem to have any display-mode/resolution-change functions! And that's pretty much the situation...

I know it's possible, but i don't know what is the class responsible (if it exists)!

The AppGameContainer class, used on the very start of the game's initialization, is the only place with any functions for changing the display-mode that I've found so far, but it's only used at the very start, and as of Slick's tutorials, is implemented as local.

```
//This is my implementation of it...
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException {
    AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Main());
//    app.setTargetFrameRate(60);
    app.setVSync(true);
    app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
    app.start();
  }
```

I can define it as a static global on the Main class, in order to use it inside the `update()` method of the options screen, but it's probably a (very) bad way to do it...

Comment: Seeing your comment below, can you answer your own question for future visitors to the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this. I found this on another site. You can cast the GameContainer object (the one you get from the update method) into an AppGameContainer method. Then you can access the setDisplayMode:

```
AppGameContainer gc = (AppGameContainer) container;
gc.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
```

[Original post here.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/37243)

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically all you have to do is create a new `AppGameContainer` object, and then re-run all your initialization code, except for code that resets the state of your game (you don't want the game to be reset to its starting state, after all).

You're right that the tutorials don't cover this, so I don't think you're missing anything. Here's a list of concerns that you'll have to handle when changing resolution. So long as you break these out into separate methods in such a way that you can re-run `init` any time in the game, then you should be fine.

- Your `render` method needs to check the current resolution with each execution when it determines what to draw. To say it another way, the `render` method shouldn't care what the current resolution is - it should just look it up each time, and do what's appropriate.
- If you're using the Slick buttons and other UI events, including event listeners, then before you re-initialize everything, you need to get a list of all the subscribed listeners, re-initialize your UI elements in the new `AppGameContainer`, and have all the listeners re-subscribe to the new elements.
- Analyze your code and look for any other place that depends on the UI being a certain state, and re-initialize it from the `init` method when the resolution changes.

So, the pseudo-code version of this is:

**When your game first starts up**:

```
main(args)
  - initi()
    if (gameStartingForTheFirstTime())
      - initUI()
      - initGameState()
      - initWhateverElseYouNeedToForYourGame()
    if (resolutionChanging())
      - initUI()
```

Comment: Actually, as proven by my testing with using the (extremely poor, but my only current way to do it) `global static` method, i just need to reinitialize the visual aspects of the display, not the whole class...more specifically, the AppGameContainer class extends the Container class, and the only code called inside AppGameContainer's setDisplayMode() that is responsible for this the whole process, as confirmed by looking the source-code, is an `if (Display.isCreated())` with Container's `initGL();` and `enterOrtho();`...and the whole trouble is caused because those two methods are `protected`.

Answer (score 2):

After also consulting gamedev.stackexchange and Slick2D's forums, the action i took to solve the problem was to use a mix between @normalocity's solution, the use of the ScalableGame interface, as well as, and most importantly, **compiling my own version of the API** (since it's open-source).

The changes to the API include, but are not limited to, a more direct access to Container's `setDisplayMode()`, with solved the problem related to this question.

For anyone with the same or similar problems, this is the solution I suggest.

EDIT-NOTE: Although my answer is still valid, and I am not developing with Slick2D, @Requios' answer is a better approach without any problems, judging by the positive votes and lack of comments pointing out any problems. So that's the approach I'd recommend, and I've accordingly switched the "chosen answer" to his, as well as cast my own upvote.